# PrimeNG - Why are not multiple filters applied in the dataview component?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, dataview

I have a project where I use the [dataview](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dataview) component. I want to do is that the user can filter by several fields at the same time, in this case name and category. The problem is that it only filters by one.

This is the complete dataview.

[image]

When I select a category, for example, '*Accesories*', only it shows products with this category.
[image]

But when I write in the input, it shows products with a category different from '*Accesories*'. Here is my problem. Multiple filters aren't applied. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

My code:

```
<p-dataView #dv [value]="products" [paginator]="true" [rows]="9" filterBy="name,category" [sortField]="sortField" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" layout="grid">
    ....
    <p-multiSelect [options]="listCategory" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory (onChange)="dv.filter($event.value)" defaultLabel="Select category"> </p-multiSelect>
    <span class="p-input-icon-left p-mb-2 p-mb-md-0">
          <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
          <input type="search" pInputText placeholder="Search by Name" (input)="dv.filter($event.target.value)">
    </span>
...
</p-dataView>
```

I have done a [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dataview-demo-mjr5cw?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to recreate the problem.

- Version Angular: 11
- Version PrimeNG: 11

Answer (score 0):

On top of the search field, try creating a custom filter/s and add them to the dataList using custom pipes, Assuming you want to filter using value of label in the dropdown:
Given a list as follows:

```
 dataList = [{
    name: 'name1'
    },

    {
    name: 'name2'
    }]
```

with dropdown select value like `{ label:'James', value:'1'}`

**Primeng dataview:**

<p-dataView [value]="dataList | FilterNamePipePipe : 'name': filterNameValue" ...

**PrimengFilter Component: databinding**

```
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="filterNameValue" ...></p-dropdown>
```

**Custom Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterNamePipe',
})
export class FilterNamePipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], name: string, value): any[] {
    // in no items are given then return null
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }

    // if search value is not yet in the input then return all items
    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
      return items;
    }
    // get key value of name in the dictionary and compare with dropdown label value
    const itemsToReturn = items.filter(
      (it) => it[field]=== value.label
    );

    return itemsToReturn;
  }
}
```